# Disable horizontal scroll; but allow vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to disable horizontal scroll on a website; **but allowing vertical scrolling.**

I have a script which works like a slider by sliding the 'body' of the page left and revealing more contents. However this creates extra empty space on the right.

I need to disable horizontal scrolling so users don't see this empty space. I tried the following script but it disables both horizontal and vertical scrolling:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
     window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

I have tried `overflow-x: hidden` but that doesn't work when the body's width is dynamic and not static.

#### Question:

Is there a way to modify the above script to disable the horizontal scrolling and keep vertical scrolling?

Answer (score 24):

You were close to get it. You need to get the `document` —*or `window`*— and bind the scroll: then you can check if the `scrollLeft` is updated to **more than 0** and set the `scrollLeft` to **0**.

The next code works well:

```
$(function() {

    var $body = $(document);
    $body.bind('scroll', function() {
        // "Disable" the horizontal scroll.
        if ($body.scrollLeft() !== 0) {
            $body.scrollLeft(0);
        }
    });

});
```

If you want to **disable horizontal scroll for an element** (*like div, for instance*) you only need to replace `$(document)` by `$("#yourElementID")`

---

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/tomloprod/zx1bvdf5/

---

> **NOTE:**
>
> The above script will prevent you scroll horizontally and, in addition, you can use the next CSS style: `overflow-x:hidden;` to hide the horizontal scroll.
>
> **And will be like if there were no horizontal scrolling.**

Answer (score 16):

This should work (CSS):

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Without JQuery:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
  window.scrollLeft = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use overflow-x:hidden on your wrapper element

`overflow-x:hidden;`

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did to solve my problem.

```js
 window.onscroll = function () {
     window.scrollTo(0,window.scrollY);
 };
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could also jQuery's "on", and check for the deltaX.

```
$("body").on("wheel", function(e) {
  var deltaX = e.originalEvent.deltaX;

  if (deltaX !== 100 && deltaX !== -100) {
    // ...do something
  }

  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden auto;
}
```

The `100vw/vh` means 100% of the view-port (=window inner) width/height.

The `hidden auto` means never show scroll on x and show scroll on y when necessary.