# Disable Scrolltop after clicking next button on form - js

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, scroll, onclick

I am using a multipage form from Form Assembly. After clicking on the next button to go to the next page, it scrolls to the top of the form cutting off the title of the page! Is there a way I can stop this happening?

Here is the form - http://futureldn.co/apply/

I removed this in the forms html...

```
<script>

input.wfPageNextButton.onclick=function(){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
};

</script>
```

However it did not work. Then I noticed...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tfaforms.com/wForms/3.8/js/wforms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    wFORMS.behaviors.prefill.skip = false;
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tfaforms.com/wForms/3.8/js/localization-en_GB.js"></script>
```

So, can I write some js to counteract what is going on in this/these js file/s?

I am not good at js at all so am having trouble interpreting it!

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Maybe this will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29431155/4359029

Comment: Do you know if I would need to add the js to the header of my site to counteract this? I keep trying different things in the form html code where it says...

    input.wfPageNextButton.onclick=function(){
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
    };

...however nothing different seems to be happening no matter what I try!

Comment: Thank you for commenting! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable horizontal scroll; but allow vertical scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678482/disable-horizontal-scroll-but-allow-vertical-scroll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you don't want to disable scrolling alltogether, we need to do something like this instead:

```
$(function() {

    var $body = $(document);
    $body.on('click','.wfPageNextButton, .wfPagePreviousButton', function() {
        // "Disable" the horizontal scroll.
        if ($body.scrollTop() !== 0) {
            $body.scrollTop(0);
        }
    });

});
```

So after a buttonclick, it will check if it has a vertical scroll, and if so, set it to 0. As to where to put it, at the end of your body is probably safest.

Noticed that while testing it on your page, it's unfamiliar with $ as shorthand for jQuery, so you might need to change the $'s into jQuery.

So

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $body = jQuery(document);
    ...
```

Comment: Adding at the bottom worked! However it disabled the scroll of the current page, how I would action this when clicking the next button? I replaced jQuery(function(){ with input.wfPageNextButton.onclick=function(){ - long shot, didn't work!

Comment: I just thought - I still want the user to have the ability to scroll the page, but just want to disable the scroll top after clicking the next button... so when the user goes to the next page, it stays in that vertical position, that's all! Not sure if that is helpful!

Comment: @tomloprod because the OP seemed so new at javascript that i wasn't sure if he could make the necesairy changes himself. Nor would he know where to put it.

Comment: @DrunkWolf Well, I think you should have written a commentary instead; but it is only my opinion.

Comment: @tomloprod perhaps you're right, i'm fairy new to SO (~2-3 weeks) myself

Comment: @user3541921 updated with the on click variant that shouldn't disable your userscroll

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help @DrunkWolf it doesn't seem to be working yet but I will keep playing around with it...

Comment: @user3541921 strange, it works for me when i add it in the console on your site, does it give any errors in  your console?

Comment: Really! Maybe adding it in the header? Don't know if that's a stupid suggestion, sorry for being a beginner at js!

Comment: @user3541921 it shouldn't matter much where you add it, as long as it's after jQuery. Can you look in console and see if you get any error messages?

Comment: I have the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: <p><script>
jQuery(function(){</p>
<p>    var $body = jQuery(document);
    $body.on('click','.wfPageNextButton, .wfPagePreviousButton', function() {
        // "Disable" the horizontal scroll.
        if ($body.scrollTop() !== 0) {
            $body.scrollTop(0);
        }
    });</p>
<p>}); 
</script></p>

Comment: Ah yeah, that ain't right :D It seems that wherever you're adding it right now, it's being parsed by something and placed it inside html wrappers line by line, which won't work :) Just add it in the same way you did with the previous one? since that one worked? @user3541921

Comment: Wordpress was adding p tags... I cleared the space and now it works! Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: @user3541921 No problem :) remember, console is your friend!