# Forbid horizontal scroll in a <div> (jquery.gantt)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how to dissable horizontal scroll in a  container? E.g. via JS.
I'm using https://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/ in the max. zoom-level, so that i don't need to horizontal scroll. nevertheless, some bars are longer and when I hover with my mouse over the  of the gantt, the horizontal scroll activates.
How to forbid that?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You could disable horizontal scroll with CSS, with `overflow-x: hidden` on the div  you are targetting

Comment: I tried it on "rightPanel" and other <div>-class but without success.

Comment: So use your browser's developer tools to find out which element those scroll bars belong to, and then set `overflow-x: hidden` for _that_ element?

Comment: That's what i'm doing, but for now no success to report.

Comment: You need to block the scroll event with with js because the horizontal-scroll is activate on the whole container, not only the gantt one. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678482/disable-horizontal-scroll-but-allow-vertical-scroll#:~:text=You%20need%20to%20get%20the,set%20the%20scrollLeft%20to%200.&text=NOTE%3A,to%20hide%20the%20horizontal%20scroll.

Comment: element.scrollNavigation.canScroll = false;

Answer (score 0):

You need to block the scroll event with with js because the horizontal-scroll is activate on the whole container, not only the gantt one. So you should search into js files.
Did you try to comment those lines (264, 265, 267 in *jquery.fn.gantt.js) ?

```
    //element.scrollNavigation.panelMargin = parseInt($dataPanel.css("left").replace("px", ""), 10);
    //element.scrollNavigation.panelMaxPos = ($dataPanel.width() - $rightPanel.width());
    //element.scrollNavigation.canScroll = ($dataPanel.width() > $rightPanel.width());
```

OR as @Wimanicesir commented try to set `element.scrollNavigation.canScroll = false;` right below the line I show you above.

Comment: That helped a lot, both ways are working, thanks @MaxiGui & Wimanicesir. Sadly, I can't scroll vertical now (whole page) :D Is there a way to differ between horizontal and vertical in the *jquery.fn.gantt.js script?

Comment: Did you comment and add the element or just comment ? or try both ?

Comment: At first i comment the lines: worked. Then i just simply added the line with element.scrollNavigation.canScroll = false; <- worked and now active (lines above are not commented).

Comment: so if you simply comment without the added line ? vertical scroll is also blocked ? Check this subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678482/disable-horizontal-scroll-but-allow-vertical-scroll.  `window.onscroll = function () {
     window.scrollTo(0,window.scrollY);
 };`